# Woocommerce Назначить шаблон для подкатегорий

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Нужно назначить разные шаблоны для родительской и дочерних категорий, т.е. если у родительской по умолчанию стоит archive-product.php, какой шаблон отвечает за вывод подкатегорий? нашла taxonomy-product-cat.php, но при переносе его в тему, он автоматически подключается как для родительских категорий, так и для дочерних.

Answer (score 0):

Такой возможности нет. Внутри файла шаблона вы должны определять, является ли категория дочерней и менять вывод для неё.

Comment: а не подскажите, как будет выглядеть этот цикл? я плохо разбираюсь в php